# MySQL: how to restore from a previously saved copy of the data directory?

Tags: mysql

I have previously saved a copy of /var/lib/mysql/ddms directory ("ddms" is the DB name). Now I installed a new MySQL on a freshly installed Ubuntu 10.04.3 LTS by running `apt-get install mysql-server`, I believe version 5.1 was installed. After I copy the ddms directory under /var/lib/mysql, some of its tables work fine, these are the tables with an associated set of three files: a .frm file, a .MYD file and a .MYI file.

However, there are two tables with a different set of files: a .frm file and a .ibd file. These two tables didn't show up in the table list in phpMyAdmin. When I look at the error log, it says:

```
[ERROR] Cannot find or open table ddms/dictionary_item from
the internal data dictionary of InnoDB though the .frm file for the
table exists. Maybe you have deleted and recreated InnoDB data
files but have forgotten to delete the corresponding .frm files
of InnoDB tables, or you have moved .frm files to another database?
or, the table contains indexes that this version of the engine
doesn't support.
```

Please help with restoring these two tables. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I was quite ticked when I saw this error myself after upgrading xampp.

I fixed it by **installing an older version of xampp into another directory (which included an older version of mysql)** and then logging back into phpmyadmin. I was then able to export the databases that didn't work in the newer version. (My tables worked in the old version but not the new version)

**Note** This was a windows install.
My old version was xampp 1.7.7 in which the included MySQL was MySQL Server 5.5